# What is the widest door I should buy if my rough opening is 65½" wide?

Tags: doors

I'm replacing a front door with sidelights on either side. My rough opening is 65½" wide.

What would be the widest door I can purchase? Can I buy a unit that is wider, i.e. 73½"?

Comment: Only purchase the wider unit if there is room to enlarge the rough opening an appropriate amount and that you or your handyman feels capable of doing so. Keep in mind that you never get a wider unit to fit into a rough opening that is too small and that the existing rough opening is probably already maxed out in width based upon construction of the abode.

Comment: Are you only replacing the door? or the door and the side lites? Is the RO for only the door?